# Convex domain is epigraph of convex functions locally around a boundary point

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-hulls

Let $D$ be a bounded convex domain in $\mathbb R^2$, if  $\xi\in\partial D$ is it true that, there exists an $R>0$ and a convex function $\gamma:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that upto suitable choice of coordinates we have
$$D\cap B(\xi,R):= \{\ (x,y)\in B(\xi,R)\ :\ y>\gamma(x)\ \}?$$ And for strictly convex domain we can we choose this function to be strictly convex ?

Suggestions for some helpful references related to this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: one can have a look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044857/779382